# Hide sensitive data inside application

Tags: android, security, retrofit

I am using retrofit request:

```
@Headers("Authorization: Basic: UsernamePassword")
@POST("services/2/something/something")
fun createPlan(@Body planData: PlanInfo): Call<Plan>
```

In my header I requred to send usrname and password and string in Base64 encode. But it not so hard to decode if decomiling the app.
So I refered to manual: https://medium.com/novumlogic/hiding-sensitive-data-in-android-app-dbd64e88224f for hiding sensitive data in android app.

But now when I use data from constant like so:

```
@Headers("Authorization: "+ConstantsEncrypted.usernamePassword())
@POST("services/2/something/something")
fun createPlan(@Body planData: PlanInfo): Call<Plan>
```

I get an error: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant.

So how can I hide this sensitive data properly?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I found other more simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using the annotation method. Here's how I have done it in my projects.

```
class Authenticator : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

        return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", ConstantsEncrypted.usernamePassword()).build()
    }

}
```

And don't forget to add it to your `OkHttpClient.Builder()` instance using `authenticator(Authenticator())` something like below:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    callTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    // your code
    // this is where you add your authenticator
    authenticator(Authenticator())
    // more code 
}.build()
```

The `Authenticator` is from package `okhttp3`. You can find more info on class [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html).

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution, sending header to the function:

```
fun createPlan(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,@Body planData: PlanInfo): Call<Plan>
```